# Can a unique_ptr take a nullptr value?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, unique-ptr, nullptr

Is this code fragment valid? :

```
unique_ptr<A> p(new A());
p = nullptr;
```

That is, can I assign `nullptr` to a `unique_ptr` ? or it will fail?

I tried this with the **g++** compiler and it worked, but what about other compilers?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**It will work**.

From Paragraphs 20.7.1.2.3/8-9 of the C++11 Standard about the `unique_ptr<>` class template:

> `unique_ptr& operator=(nullptr_t) noexcept`;
>
> *Effects*: `reset()`.
>
> *Postcondition*: `get() == nullptr`

This means that the definition of class template `unique_ptr<>` includes an overload of `operator =` that accepts a value of type `nullptr_t` (such as `nullptr`) as its right hand side; the paragraph also specifies that assigning `nullptr` to a `unique_ptr` is equivalent to resetting the `unique_ptr`.

Thus, after this assignment, your `A` object will be destroyed.

Comment: I see. BTW, only nullptr has nullptr_t, thats the way it's done, isn't?

Comment: @Zhen: The standard does not specify this. You could create a variable of type `nullptr_t`, but I doubt you will ever need to do that.

Answer (score 3):

More common case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
    A() {std::cout << "A::A()" << std::endl;}
    ~A() {std::cout << "A::~A()" << std::endl;}
};

class B {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<A> pA;
    B() {std::cout << "B::B()" << std::endl;}
    ~B() { std::cout << "B::~B()" << std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> p1(new A());

    B b;
    b.pA = std::move(p1);
}
```

Output:

```
A::A()
B::B()
B::~B()
A::~A()
```

This code example can be non-intuitive:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
    A() {std::cout << "A::A()" << std::endl;}
    ~A() {std::cout << "A::~A()" << std::endl;}
};

class B {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<A> pA;
    B() {std::cout << "B::B()" << std::endl;}
    ~B() 
    {
        if (pA)
        {
            std::cout << "pA not nullptr!" << std::endl;
            pA = nullptr; // Will call A::~A()
        }
        std::cout << "B::~B()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> p1(new A());

    B b;
    b.pA = std::move(p1);
}
```

Output:

```
A::A()
B::B()
pA not nullptr!
A::~A()
B::~B()
```